# How to bridge two interfaces both on different networks with different IP addresses in OpenWRT?

Tags: linux, routing, dhcp, openwrt

My embedded Linux device—running OpenWRT—has two interfaces that are `ath0` and `ath1`. `ath0` is a WLAN port also runs a DHCP server. `ath1` is used for Internet connection.

Now, I have to setup these interfaces on bridged mode in `br0` for some reasons, and let WLAN port also enable Internet connection. The reason being the ath0-WLAN-network `dhcpd` will not assigns IP to WLAN clients when ath1 connected to home AP/Internet, and WLAN clients will show a message “authentication error occurred.”

How can I bridge two interfaces both on different networks with different IP addresses?

Could I use the routing table to finish it?

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  If you want eth0 and eth1 to be on different networks with different IP addresses, then they should not be bridged.  Please [edit] your question so that it explains what you are trying to do.

Comment: I know. But they must be add in br0 for some reason. Thank you for your help. I will discuss with my FAE and cite this thread.

Comment: OK. I edited my question clean.

Comment: A bridge by definition is joining two networks into one network.  You should probably add both IP addresses to the bridge interface rather than the eth interaces.  It would help immensely if you explained *why* they must be bridge rather than just "reasons".

Comment: About the "reasons". The ath0-WLAN-network dhcpd will not assigns IP to WLAN clients when ath1 connected to home AP/Internet, and WLAN clients will show a message “authentication error occurred”.